# reload a page without losing field values like in FireFox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript and HTML.

I have a simple html form that has some select fields. When the user selects the options from the fields, a function is called that takes the values of the fields, multiples the values against other field values and spits out the results to an input text field named "result".

This is all working great, however I would love a way that instead of outputting the results to a text field, it would output as standard text on the page.

What I did was call the calculate function the  tag, within the body, I inserted a document.write(result), then I created a button that calls the calculate function in addition to location.reload().

In Firefox, it works perfectly where it KEEPS the options selected, calculates the results, reloads the page and updates the document.write(result) value on the page.
But in IE or Safari, it resets the select options values to the default settings.

I hope this makes sense and appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

every time the user selects an option, or makes any sort of a selection, serialize that control, and slap the serialized string to the end of the current window.location, then navigate to it.

also, you will need to add javascript to check the current url, figure out what selection was made, and pro grammatically change the control's values. this way, when the user refreshes the page, the url will contain all of his selections.

got it?

Comment: that's not really a good solution. the URL ends up messy and unsightly. - pardon me, i look for beauty in programming.

Comment: I dont see your solution here

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.write` you could setup an element used specifically to hold the output value much like you do currently with the input element.

In place of the current input element used to output the result..

```
<span id="calculationResult"></span>
```

Then to populate that value and avoid reloading the page at all so that your fields maintain current values..

```
document.getElementById("calculationResult").innerHTML = result;
```

if you need to append you can always just create text nodes and append to the element which would be preferred anyway.

Comment: Using .innerHTML is not recommended, as it is a non-standard method.

Comment: I agree it isn't recommended, that is why I stated that adding text nodes as children of the span would be the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep text boxes' content as is, set the button as `type="button"` and call the calculate function and document.write in `onclick`. No reload, no mess.